# Forgetting a Strand in Braid Groups

Tags: geometric-topology, group-presentation, braid-groups

Let $B_n$ be the braid group of $n$ strings over the unit disk $D$. Let $$d_i:B_n\to B_{n-1}$$ be the operation which is obtained by forgetting the $i$-th strand, $1\leq i\leq n$. Geometrically this "forgetting operation" is clear.

However, if we use the Artin presentation of the braid group; namely, define $B_n$ as the group with generators $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_{n-1}$ satisfying the following relations:

[image]

Then how to describe the "forgetting operation" $d_i$?

Comment: The forgetting operation induces a map $S_n\to S_{n-1}$ of the corresponding symmetric groups. Have you tried to describe it?

Comment: @O.L., thank you for your comment. Let $\sigma\in S_n$ and let $\tilde{\sigma}\in S_{n-1}$ be induced by $\sigma$ by forgetting the $i$th strand. Then for $k\in\{1,\cdots,n-1\}$, $\tilde{\sigma}(k)=\sigma(k)$ if $\sigma(k)<\sigma(i)$ and $\tilde{\sigma}(k)=\sigma(k)-1$ if $\sigma(k)>\sigma(i)$; right? How then does this help to describe $d_i$?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is: Since, say, the  operation $d_n$ is not a group homomorphism, describing images of Artin generators under $d$ says very little about $d$ itself. Do you want an algorithm converting products of $\sigma_i$'s ($i\le n-1$) to products of $\sigma_j$ ($j\le n-2$)? Even for the permutation group, this looks quite hideous.

Comment: @studiosus, I am aware that $d_i$ is not a homomorphism. But this map has a very clear geometric meaning. Thus I wonder if $B_n$ is defined using the Artin presentation, there should be a way to define $d_i$ such that it agrees with the intuitive geometric definition. Someone mentioned that it is related to crossed simplicial groups; but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This is totally not correct, although I will leave it up for posterity's sake.

It is clear that this can't be right; as suggested in the comments, if we look at $B_3$ which has two generators $\sigma_i$ satisfying
$$
\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2
$$
then if we "forgot" the last strand as I suggested by setting $\sigma_2 = 1$, then this would yield a group with one generator $\sigma_1$ satisfying $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_1$, i.e. the trivial group. So this is clearly not correct.

**Original answer**

If you think of the generators $\sigma_i$ as swapping the $i$-th string and the $(i+1)$-st string, then it should be easy to see that forgetting the $n$-th strand is equivalent to setting $\sigma_{n-1} = 1$ (since if you forget that string, twirling the previous string around... nothing... does nothing).

So at least in the simplest case (strings at either end, really), this is what the forgetting map does. I believe (though I haven't bothered with the details) that forgetting other strands is similar, with some sort of conjugacy argument.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In $B_3$, consider the braid $\sigma_2\sigma_1$. Forgetting the 3rd strand yields the trivial element in $B_2$, instead of $\sigma_1$. So it might not be equivalent as simply setting $\sigma_{n-1}=1$.

Comment: You are totally correct! Looking at it more carefully, what I said clearly isn't true: $B_3$ has two generators and the single relation $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$. If we simply set $\sigma_2 = 1$, then this would yield a group with one generator and the relation $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_1$, which is clearly not the case. That's what I get for not checking my work...

Answer (score 0):

I think one could regard the braid group as $\pi_0(Diff(D^2-\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}))$.  Then this diffeomorphism group has a natural forgetful map to the Diff of disk removing one less point.